# Time complexity of decreasing elements in Math.max() in for-loop?

Tags: time-complexity

How do you assess the time complexity when the values continue to decrease? In this example, let's assume the length of the array can be any length so the length of the input array is of length `n`;

- The for-loop is O(n) complexity
- `Math.max()` in javascript is O(m) for the number of elements to assess (?)

So the total time complexity is O(n*m)?

Or do you assume only the worst case when `m===n`, so the time complexity is O(n^2)?

Contrived example below:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
const n = arr.length;

for (let i=0; i<n; i++) {
   const max = Math.max(...arr);
   arr.pop();
   console.log({arr,max});
}
```

Comment: Assuming `splice` is O(1), It's O(n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1). No need for "m".

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Does that simiplify into something cleaner function wise or in Big O complexity form? It looks like a factorial but it's addition... Also, thanks for your note and observation. I changed the splice operation to `.pop()`.

Comment: Yes, it's an arithmetic series.